# Views related to a mysql table

Tags: mysql, view

How can I get all the views related to a table?
I want to alter that table but don't know which views use it in their select query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but I think this might work.

The `INFORMATION SCHEMA` holds the metadata of your databases, including (among many other things), information about views.

So something like this might be useful:

```
select *
from information_sechema.views
where view_definition like '%yourTableName%'
```

Reference:

- [MySQL Reference Manual: The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` `VIEWS` table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views-table.html)